# Are these descriptions of standard deviation and standard error correct?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error

I'm having a hard time verbalizing the difference between these two concepts. How does this sound?

Standard deviation: perform a measurement; there is a 68% chance that that measurement will be within
one standard deviation of the sample mean. 
Qualitatively, measures scatter/variation/dispersion of the data. 
It does not change with sample size (assuming large N).

Standard deviation of the mean (or standard error): perform a series of measurements; there is a 68% chance that that sample mean (or average) will be within one “standard deviation of the mean” of the population mean.
Decreases with increasing sample size.

Comment: Not quite right. The standard error description is closer. For that one, is better to say standard error = "standard deviation of the *sample* mean". In contrast, for your standard deviation description, you should say "*population* mean". The other issue is that your 68% number assumes a normal distribution. For the standard error this is OK if the sample size is "large". However, for the standard deviation the 68% number does not generally apply.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 thanks. yes, for my situation, normal dist. is assumed. I am not sure why in st. dev. description it would be population mean. I take a bunch of data that have normal dist. The mean of that data is the sample mean, right? The population mean would be the mean of the entire population, no?

Comment: For a normal distribution, the measurement will be within 1 standard deviation of the *population* mean 68% of the time. Because of the standard *error*, your sample mean could be further away.

Comment: Just to add that it may help to think of them as both standard deviations but of different distributions.

Comment: @geomatt if we rely on sample quantities it's not just the error in the mean you need to worry about; the error on the standard deviation is also there.

Comment: @Glen_b quite right. When reading the question I (carelessly) assumed *population* standard deviation was intended in the first query.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, in the case of the normal the standard error of the sample standard deviation is asymptotically $\sqrt{\frac{_1}{^2}}\approx 71\%$ the standard error of the mean (rather than a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ larger as I'd have guessed)